# Looping through dictionary and get each value C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm using the following code to get each value of a dictionary and its index

```
foreach (var termIndex in freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key)))
{
     var wordFreq = entry.Value;
     ........
}
```

Why does suddenly an error

> *the name 'entry' doesn't exist in the current context*

appear?? Could anyone help please ?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To iterate over the dictionary elements all you have to do is:

```
foreach (var entry in freq)
{
    var wordFreq = entry.Value;
    ........
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`entry` is defined in the lambda - in the parameter to `Select` and is only in scope within it.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining two iterators over your dictionary: the `foreach` loop and the `Select` operation. You should probably merge them into one:

```
foreach (var entry in freq)
{
    var termIndex = GetTermIndex(entry.Key);
    var wordFreq = entry.Value;
    // ........
    // ........
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `entry=>GetTermIndex(entry.Key)` is lambda function. It has incoming parameter 'entry' of and outgoing parameter of type that equal to return type GetTermIndex method.

```
freq.Select(entry => GetTermIndex(entry.Key))
```

is equivalent to:

```
foreach(var entry in freq)
{
    yield return GetTermIndex(entry.Key);
}
```

entry second code fragment is exists locally in foreach and cannot be accessed outside of it.
Compiler says it to you.

You should rewrite your code to:

```
        foreach (var entry in freq)
        {
            var termIndex = GetTermIndex(entry.Key));
            var wordFreq = entry.Value;
            ........
            ........
        }
```

Comment: Well, actually it's not completely equivalent (at least method call should be added), but +1

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
...
var wordFreq = entry.Value;
...
```

To:

```
...
var wordFreq = termIndex.Value;
...
```

Because this is the object in the foreach, entry is in the scope of the lambda expression